# dropdown list keep selected last value entered php

Tags: php, drop-down-menu

I have created a user profile page in php. The user inserts gender and telephone number and all these are stored in database in a table called profile. My question is how can I make the dropdown list to keep the selected value entered by user previous time. For example, if the user chooses Male, the dropdown list should keep Male as a selected option, and change only when the user decides to change it again.

Here is the code:

```
<form   action=""   method="POST"  >      
<?php

if ( isset($_GET['success']) === true && empty($_GET['success'])===true ){
    echo'Profile Updated Sucessfuly';
}else{
    if( empty($_POST) === false  &&  empty($errors) === true ){
        $update_data_profile = array('gender' => $_POST['gender'],
                                                 'telephone' => $_POST['telephone']);

        update_user_profile($session_user_id, $update_data_profile);
        header('Location: profile_update.php?success');                             
        exit();
    }else if ( empty($errors) === false ){
        echo output_errors($errors);
    }
?>


Gender<select name="gender"  id="gender"> 
    <option value=" "> EMPTY </option> 
    <option value="Male">Male</option> 
    <option value="Female">Female</option> 
</select>

Telephone <input name="telephone" type="text" size="25" />

<input type="submit" value="" name="submit"/></br>
```

This is the function that I use to insert data in database:

```
function update_user_profile($user_id, $update_data_profile){

   $result = mysql_query("select user_id from profile where user_id = $user_id limit 1");

     $user_id = $update_data_profile['user_id'] ;

    if(count($update_data_profile)){

    $columns = array();
    $values = array();

    foreach($update_data_profile as $field => $data){
    $columns[] = $field;
    $values[] = $data;
    } 
    }

mysql_query(" INSERT INTO `profile` (" . implode(",", $columns) .") values ('" . implode("','", $values) . "')" ) or die (mysql_error());
```

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? Yes you have given us code of what you have done, but what have you tried to accomplish your question? Hint: [HTML Option Selected](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp)

Comment: nothing yet I don't know how

Comment: Why not store those posted values in the users session OR cookie and If they are present, default the values in the form

Comment: So you want the dropdown to be populated from the database the next time a user hits the page?

Comment: yes probably the dropdown to be populated from the database... I cannot imagine any other way

Comment: so if two users enter data 1:male, 2:female, then next entry by 1 would default to? As you don't store who did what.

Answer (score 0):

From this you will get the logics

```
<select name="gender" id="gender">
<?php
  if($_POST['gender'] == 'male' {
    echo '<option value="Male" selected>Male</option>';
  } else {
    echo '<option value="Female" selected>Female</option>';
?> 
</select>
```

Comment: best to use selected="selected"

Comment: In XHTML, attribute minimization is forbidden, and the selected attribute must be defined as <option selected="selected">

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the last Gender during page load and add the selected option.

```
<?php
    result = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT user_id FROM profile ORDER BY user_id DESC LIMIT 1"));
    $gender = $result['gender'];  //you need to change the ['gender'] with what your column name is for gender.
?>
<select name="gender"  id="gender"> 
    <option value=" "> EMPTY </option> 
    <option value="Male" <?php if($gender == "Male") echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>Male</option> 
    <option value="Female" <?php if($gender == "Female") echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>Female</option> 
</select>
```

Comment: where exactly in my code I should copy and paste the first 2 lines you wrote, because I get an error for this line $gender = $result['gender'];

Comment: anywhere before that section you can put in <?php  ?> I'll update the code for you

Answer (score -1):

You can change the code like this:

```
<select name="gender"  id="gender" default="Male">
```